# No overload for method 'zwierze' takes 0 arguments c#

Tags: c#, variables, random

I haven't any errors, but the program always generates 0 for AnimalAge. It should generate numbers from 1-20. This is a simple game where a player should find Age of Animal. Corrected, still get 0.

```
 public class losowaniez
{
    public int AnimalAge;
    public static Random AnimalAge1 = new Random();
    public int Age2
    {
        get
        {                
            return AnimalAge1.Next(20);
        }            
    }                
}

    public class Animal 
    {
        public void Fish()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Zwierze moze miec maksymalnie 10 lat, zgadnij ile ma lat");
            int x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        public int zwierze(losowaniez c)
        {                
            int AnimalAge = c.Age2;

            Console.WriteLine("Zwierze moze miec maksymalnie 20 lat zgadnij ile ma lat");
            int x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if (x == AnimalAge)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Wygrales gre");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            else if (x > AnimalAge)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Celuj nizej!");
                zwierze();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Celuj wyzej!");
                zwierze();
            }
        }
             }
```

Comment: @TaW - No, it's not that problem. There is a Readline() here.

Answer (score 2):

add a constructor to the class losowaniez and do the assigning of Age2 in the Constructor.

Your class would be

```
public class losowaniez
{
    public int AnimalAge;
    public int Age2;
    public losowaniez()
    {
        int AnimalAge;

        Random RandomObj = new Random();
        AnimalAge = RandomObj.Next(20);
        Age2 = AnimalAge;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should definitely make RandomObj  a static private field. Creating a new Random object for every call of .Next() is bad practise.

Answer (score 1):

you should do something like this

Change your `losowanie()` method  as below method

```
public int losowanie()
{
    Random RandomObj = new Random();
    Age2 = RandomObj.Next(20);
    return Age2;
}
```

Call above function inside `zwierze()` like this

```
losowaniez MyAnimal = new losowaniez();
int AnimalAge = MyAnimal.losowanie();
```

Alternatively You can Create Public Property in your `losowaniez` class

```
public int Age2
{
        get {
              Random RandomObj = new Random();
              return  RandomObj.Next(20); 
            }
}
```

after creating property your  this code will work

```
        losowaniez MyAnimal = new losowaniez();
        int AnimalAge = MyAnimal.Age2;
```

Comment: Close, but this `losowanie` might as well be static. I think the OP wanted a mutating method.

Comment: @Eathrabaria - you simply were never calling `losowanie()`. Learn to use the debugger, it's not hard.

Comment: You should definitely make RandomObj  a static private field. Creating a new Random object for every call of .Next() is bad practise.

Comment: @HenkHolterman i think  OP wanted this he is trying to get this  in his code that is why i suggest to make property